# Special letters in hovering data in map plots (Plotly Express)

Tags: python, express, dictionary, plotly, visualization

I've used Plotly Express for categorizing different zones in Denmark. Is there a way to include special letters (in my case: 'æ', 'ø', 'å')? When hovering over the cities of my map of Denmark, these letters are just displayed as a square with a question mark.

[image: Example picture]

```
import plotly.express as px
import json
import pandas as pd

# Load data
with open("map1.geojson") as f:
    geo_data = json.load(f)

df = pd.read_csv("postnr12.csv",
                   dtype={"fips": str})

fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(df,
                    locations=df["Postnummer"],
                    geojson = geo_data,
                    color = df["Zone"],
                    featureidkey = "properties.POSTNR_TXT",
                    hover_name = 'Postnummer', #info ved de forskellige lokationer
                    hover_data = (['by']), #showscale = False, text = df["by"], name = ' ',
                    mapbox_style="stamen-terrain",
                    center = {"lat": 56.26392, "lon": 9.501785},
                    zoom=5.5, opacity=0.4,)
#fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=False)
fig.update_layout(coloraxis_showscale=False)
```

[![CSV][2]][2]

Comment: I tried creating a df similar to yours with the special characters you specifically mentioned, but I cannot reproduce your error: they render on the chloropleth mapbox as expected for me. Can you include a sample of your .csv file in the question so we can see if the special characters are somehow different?

Answer (score 1):

Normally I wouldn't post an "answer" that might not solve the problem, but this is for the purpose of helping you debug what the issue may be. I'll update my answer if we figure it out.

This might have to do with your version of Plotly (`is your version of Plotly up to date?`). Try running the following code below and let me know if the same issue is still occurring (`if you are able to see special characters when you run the code below - then that means it probably has something to do with your .csv file`). A final possibility is that your browser is having trouble rendering special characters in html. I don't think it's likely if you're using a modern browser but it might be possible.

The below code creates a chloropleth mapbox using a sample `df` that contains the special characters you mentioned, and it renders properly for me in Chrome.

```
import numpy as np
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
with urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/geojson-counties-fips.json') as response:
    counties = json.load(response)

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/fips-unemp-16.csv",
                   dtype={"fips": str})

import plotly.express as px

## subset the df for a sample
df_subset = df.iloc[:75].copy()

## randomly choose the characters
np.random.seed(42)
special_characters = np.random.choice(['å','æ', 'ø'],75)
df_subset['by'] = special_characters

fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(df_subset, geojson=counties, locations='fips', color='unemp',
                           color_continuous_scale="Viridis",
                           range_color=(0, 12),
                           mapbox_style="carto-positron",
                           zoom=6, center = {"lat": 32.3182, "lon": -86.9023},
                           opacity=0.5,
                           hover_data = (['by']),
                           labels={'unemp':'unemployment rate'}
                          )
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've updated Plotly to version 5.5.0, but the error still occurs and I'm also using Chrome. When I tried to upload the CSV-file here, it also mischaracterized the special characters, but I've included an image of some of the rows. It should be fine, right?

Comment: @NiklasMatzenGroth can you include a portion of the .csv as text instead of an image? That way I can try to copy and paste the special characters that are present in the file. Also when you run my code, do the special characters display in Chrome?

Comment: Since you said it's probably my .csv-file that was the problem, I tried to redo it from .txt-file into another .csv-file. Now it works! Thanks Derek.